# How to generate nested column for a particular group of columns in XSL FO dynamically

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xsl-fo

I have an XSLT 1.0 stylesheet which generates a table with multiple columns and rows for the below XML. The desired output i am looking for is to create a nested parent column for a group of columns, lets say in my XML, the 3 columns( '**PromotionInd**', '**BrkChgID**', '**BrkChgAmt**') need to be nested under one parent column '**Brokerage**' as shown in the below image.[Desired nested columns layout picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUkwR.png)

Below is my XML and XSLT. Can you please guide me achieving this.

**XML Data**

```
     <PdfPrinter>
     <Reports>
     <Report>
     <BatchDate>2016-08-10T00:00:00</BatchDate>
     <ClientAccountNo>ABCDE01384</ClientAccountNo>
     <Source>N</Source>
     <CDSNo>0000001387</CDSNo>
     <Price>0.123000</Price>
     <Qty>-1200</Qty>
     <TCurrency>USD</TCurrency>
     <TNettAmt>0</TNettAmt>
     <LCurrency>USD</LCurrency>
     <LNettAmt>-86.600000</LNettAmt>
     <PromotionInd>N</PromotionInd>
     <BrkChgID>BRK-N</BrkChgID>
     <BrkChgAmt>50.000000</BrkChgAmt>
     <ClrChgID>CLR</ClrChgID>
     <ClrChgAmt>10.000000</ClrChgAmt>
     <SdcChgID>SDC</SdcChgID>
     <SdcChgAmt>1.000000</SdcChgAmt>
     <BinChgID />
     <BinChgAmt>0</BinChgAmt>
     <OthChgAmt>0.000000</OthChgAmt>
     <TaxAmt>0.000000</TaxAmt>
     </Report>
     <Report>
     <BatchDate>2016-08-10T00:00:00</BatchDate>
     <ClientAccountNo />
     <Source>N</Source>
     <CDSNo />
     <Price>0.123000</Price>
     <Qty>1200</Qty>
     <TCurrency>USD</TCurrency>
     <TNettAmt>0</TNettAmt>
     <LCurrency>USD</LCurrency>
     <LNettAmt>147.600000</LNettAmt>
     <PromotionInd>N</PromotionInd>
     <BrkChgID />
     <BrkChgAmt>0</BrkChgAmt>
     <ClrChgID />
     <ClrChgAmt>0</ClrChgAmt>
     <SdcChgID />
     <SdcChgAmt>0</SdcChgAmt>
     <BinChgID />
     <BinChgAmt>0</BinChgAmt>
     <OthChgAmt>0</OthChgAmt>
     <TaxAmt>0</TaxAmt>
     </Report>
     <Report>
     <BatchDate>2016-08-10T00:00:00</BatchDate>
     <ClientAccountNo>ABCDE00003</ClientAccountNo>
     <Source>N</Source>
     <CDSNo>0000000003</CDSNo>
     <Price>1.589000</Price>
     <Qty>-2000</Qty>
     <TCurrency>USD</TCurrency>
     <TNettAmt>0</TNettAmt>
     <LCurrency>USD</LCurrency>
     <LNettAmt>-3114.820000</LNettAmt>
     <PromotionInd>N</PromotionInd>
     <BrkChgID>BRK-N</BrkChgID>
     <BrkChgAmt>50.000000</BrkChgAmt>
     <ClrChgID>CLR</ClrChgID>
     <ClrChgAmt>10.000000</ClrChgAmt>
     <SdcChgID>SDC</SdcChgID>
     <SdcChgAmt>3.180000</SdcChgAmt>
     <BinChgID />
     <BinChgAmt>0</BinChgAmt>
     <OthChgAmt>0.000000</OthChgAmt>
     <TaxAmt>0.000000</TaxAmt>
    </Report>
    </Reports>
    </PdfPrinter>
```

**EDIT : Complete XSLT 1.0 template**

```
       <xsl:stylesheet
        version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
       xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
       xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
       xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common"
       xmlns:utilityExtension="pdfprinter:extensions:utility"
       exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl utilityExtension">
      <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" 
      omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="utf-8"/>

     <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:variable name="PromotionInd" select="/PdfPrinter/
      Reports/Report/PromotionInd" />
    <xsl:variable name="ClrChgID" 
    select="/PdfPrinter/Reports/Report/ClrChgID"/>

<xsl:variable name="Brokerage">Brokerage</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="ClearingFee">Clearing Fee</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="columnFontSize">12pt</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="columnFontType">Helvetica</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="headerOrgName">Pavan</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="headerPrintedBy">Printed By</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="headerPrintedDate">Printed Date</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="headerReportID">Report ID</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="headerLogo" select="
 utilityExtension:MapPath('~/App_Data/Resources/IMAGES/logo.jpg')"/>

<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
  <!-- defines the layout master -->
  <fo:layout-master-set>
    <fo:simple-page-master master-name="all-pages" page-width="894mm" page-height="1300pt" margin-top="10mm" margin-left="20mm" margin-right="20mm" margin-bottom="10mm">
      <fo:region-body region-name="xsl-region-body" column-gap="0in" margin="0.8in" margin-left="0.7in" margin-top="2.3in" margin-bottom="1.8in" padding-top="0in"/>
      <fo:region-before region-name="xsl-region-before" extent="75mm" />
      <fo:region-after region-name="xsl-region-after" extent="7in"/>
    </fo:simple-page-master>
    <fo:page-sequence-master master-name="default-sequence">
      <fo:single-page-master-reference master-reference="all-pages"/>
      <fo:repeatable-page-master-reference  master-reference="all-pages" />
    </fo:page-sequence-master>
  </fo:layout-master-set>
  <!-- starts actual layout -->
  <fo:page-sequence master-reference="default-sequence" initial-page-number="1" id="last-page">
    <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-before" width="100%" border-top-style="solid" border-top-color="rgb(192,192,192)" padding-top="1pt">
      <fo:block>
        <fo:table border-collapse="collapse" width="100%" table-layout="fixed" margin-top="-0.002in" padding-left="0.7in" margin-left="0in" border-spacing="5px" space-before.conditionality="retain" space-after.conditionality="retain" space-after="1em" space-before="1em">
          <fo:table-column column-width="proportional-column-width(55)" column-number="1"/>
          <fo:table-column column-width="proportional-column-width(45)" column-number="2"/>
          <fo:table-column column-width="proportional-column-width(45)" column-number="3"/>
          <fo:table-column column-width="proportional-column-width(45)" column-number="4"/>
          <fo:table-column column-width="proportional-column-width(45)" column-number="5"/>
          <fo:table-body>
            <fo:table-row>
              <fo:table-cell width="50%" text-align="left" padding-left="2pt">
                <fo:block color="rgb(0,0,128)" font-size="16pt" font-weight="bold">&#160;</fo:block>
                <fo:block color="rgb(0,0,128)" font-weight="bold"></fo:block>
                <fo:block padding-left="0in">
                  <fo:external-graphic src="{$headerLogo}"/>&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;
                  <fo:block>
                  </fo:block>
                </fo:block>
                <fo:block color="rgb(0,0,128)" font-weight="bold">&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;</fo:block>
                <fo:block color="rgb(0,0,0)" font-weight="bold" font-family="{$columnFontType}" font-size="{$columnFontSize}">
                  <xsl:value-of select="$headerReportID"/> : <xsl:value-of select="/PdfPrinter/Reports/Header/ReportID" />
                </fo:block>
              </fo:table-cell>
              <fo:table-cell></fo:table-cell>
              <fo:table-cell></fo:table-cell>
              <fo:table-cell></fo:table-cell>
              <fo:table-cell width="100%" text-align="left">
                <fo:block>&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;</fo:block>
                <fo:block>&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;</fo:block>
                <fo:block>&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;</fo:block>
                <fo:block>&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;</fo:block>
                <fo:block>&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;</fo:block>
                <fo:block text-align="left">
                  <fo:inline font-weight="bold" font-family="{$columnFontType}" font-size="{$columnFontSize}">
                    Page <fo:page-number/> of <fo:page-number-citation ref-id="last-page"/>
                  </fo:inline>
                </fo:block>
                <fo:block text-align="left">
                  <fo:inline font-weight="bold" font-family="{$columnFontType}" font-size="{$columnFontSize}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$headerPrintedBy"/>  : <xsl:value-of select="$n"/>
                  </fo:inline>
                </fo:block>
                <fo:block text-align="left">
                  <fo:inline font-weight="bold" font-family="{$columnFontType}" font-size="{$columnFontSize}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$headerPrintedDate"/>  :  <xsl:value-of select="/PdfPrinter/Reports/Header/PrintedDate" />
                  </fo:inline>
                </fo:block>
              </fo:table-cell>
            </fo:table-row>
          </fo:table-body>
        </fo:table>
        <fo:block/>
      </fo:block>
      <fo:block text-align="center">
        <fo:table padding-left="0.7in" border-bottom-width="5pt" border-width="1pt" font-weight="bold" inline-progression-dimension="auto" width="100%">
          <fo:table-column column-number="1"/>
          <fo:table-body>
            <fo:table-row border-bottom-color="rgb(0,0,255)" display-align="before">
              <fo:table-cell border-bottom-width="3pt" border-bottom-style="solid" border-bottom-color="rgb(255,255,255)" padding="2pt" text-align="left">
                <fo:block text-align="center" font-size="13pt" font-weight="bold" font-family="Helvetica" border-bottom="10pt  "></fo:block>
                <fo:block>
                  <xsl:value-of select="/PdfPrinter/Reports/Header/ReportTitle" />
                </fo:block>
                <fo:block border-bottom-width="8pt" text-align="center" background-color="black"/>
              </fo:table-cell>
            </fo:table-row>
          </fo:table-body>
        </fo:table>
      </fo:block>
    </fo:static-content>
    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
      <fo:block text-align="center">
        <!-- table start -->
        <fo:table role="html:table" table-layout="auto" inline-progression-dimension="auto" line-height="2.5" width="100%" border="0px" border-collapse="collapse" border-spacing="3px" border-style="outset hidden" space-before.conditionality="retain" space-after.conditionality="retain" space-after="1em" space-before="1em">
          <!--table header-->
          <xsl:for-each select="/PdfPrinter/Reports/Report[1]/*">
            <fo:table-column column-width="proportional-column-width(4.77)" />
          </xsl:for-each>
          <fo:table-header>
            <fo:table-row height="auto" color="#FFFFFF" background-color="#A1A1A1" text-align="center" font-weight="bold" font-family="Helvetica" font-size="medium">
                <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$PromotionInd">
                  <fo:table-cell text-align="center">
                    <fo:block font-size="13pt" font-family="Helvetica">
                      <xsl:value-of select="$Brokerage"/>
                    </fo:block>
                  </fo:table-cell>
                </xsl:when>
              </xsl:choose>
              <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$ClrChgID">
                  <fo:table-cell text-align="center">
                    <fo:block font-size="13pt" font-family="Helvetica">
                      <xsl:value-of select="$ClearingFee"/>
                    </fo:block>
                  </fo:table-cell>
                </xsl:when>
              </xsl:choose>
            </fo:table-row>
            <fo:table-row height="auto" color="#FFFFFF" background-color="#A1A1A1" text-align="center" font-weight="bold" font-family="Helvetica" font-size="medium">
              <xsl:for-each select="/PdfPrinter/Reports/Report[1]/*">
                <fo:table-cell text-align="center">
                  <fo:block font-size="13pt" font-family="Helvetica">
                    <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
                  </fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
              </xsl:for-each>
            </fo:table-row>
          </fo:table-header>
          <!--table body-->
          <fo:table-body>
            <xsl:for-each select="PdfPrinter/Reports/Report">
              <fo:table-row display-align="before">
                <xsl:for-each select="*">
                  <fo:table-cell text-align="center" border-top-color="rgb(255, 255, 255)" border-top-style="solid" border-width="1pt" padding="2pt">
                    <fo:block font-size="13pt" font-family="Helvetica">
                      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </fo:block>
                  </fo:table-cell>
                </xsl:for-each>
              </fo:table-row>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </fo:table-body>
        </fo:table>
        <!-- table end -->
      </fo:block>
      <fo:block id="last-page"/>
    </fo:flow>
  </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

Comment: Please post a **reproducible** example, including a minimal, but **complete** stylesheet - one we can copy and run as is. See: [mcve].

Comment: @michael.hor257k : Thanks for the reply, Let me post the complete XSLT with XML data, The desired output i am looking for is in the OP image link. Kindly refer to it. Thanks!

Comment: "*Let me post the complete XSLT with XML data*" Please post only what's necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @michael.hor257k : Edited my XSLT template, Removed the old template and copied the full one for you to check the output.Please let me know if you need anything else. Thanks!

Comment: I don't need anything, thank you for asking. Good luck finding someone who has time to go through all this.

Comment: @michael.hor257k: Ok, I hope so.. Thanks!

Comment: Any help is greatly appreciated, stuck in the middle.. Thanks

Comment: I guess the XSL FO is simply dead.. Sad.. Thank you..

Comment: I don;'t think so. I think your XSL is so far off that it would take several hours for someone to even begin to instruct you on how even to write XSL. You have no templates except one, it is so rudimentary that it shows no experience. What you ask could be written in a few hours and yet you think someone should write it for you?

Comment: @ Kevin Brown : As you said, I am very new to XSL FO and trying to improvise. My intention was not to expect the answer from you, rather some one would guide me. Any how my sincere apologies if i have hurt anyone. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm able to resolve this with the below logic.

```
     <fo:table-row height="auto" color="#FFFFFF" background-color="#A1A1A1" text-align="center" font-weight="bold" font-family="Helvetica" font-size="medium">
              <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="/PdfPrinter/Reports/Report[1]/*[local-name()='BrkChgID']">
                   <fo:table-cell text-align="center" column-number="16" number-columns-spanned="3">
                   <fo:block font-size="13pt" font-family="Helvetica">
                      <xsl:value-of select="$Brokerage"/>
                   </fo:block>
                   </fo:table-cell>
                </xsl:when>
              </xsl:choose>
            </fo:table-row>
```